# Compute the GCD of three polynomials.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have tried to compute the GCD of the polynomials:

$f:=x^3+x^2-4x-4$

$g:=x^3-x^2-4x+4$

$h:=x^3-2x^2-x+2$.

Here is what I have done. Knowing that $GCD(f,g,h)=GCD(f,GCD(g,h))$, I first compute $GCD(g,h)$:

$x^3-2x^2-x+2-(x^3-x^2-4x+4)=-x^2+3x-2$

$x^3-x^2-4x+4-(-x-2)(-x^2+3x-2)=0$

So $GCD(g,h)=GCD(x^3-2x^2-x+2,x^3-x^2-4x+4)=-x^2+3x-2$.

Now I compute $GCD(x^3+x^2-4x-4, -x^2+3x-2)$ and get:

$(x^3+x^2-4x-4)-(-x-4)(-x^2+3x-2)=6x-12$

$(-x^2+3x+2)-(-x/6-5/6)(6x-12)=-8$

$(6x-2)-(-8)(-3x/4-1/4)=0$

I conclude that $GCD(f,g,h)=-8$. BUT when I used the gcd function in Maple, it returned $GCD(g,h)=x^2-3x+2$ and $GCD(f,x^2-3x+2)=1$. Can someone please point out my mistake? Thank you.

Comment: You have a sign mistake on the line finishing by "-8".

Comment: @Sary why is it supposed to be positive?

Comment: Actually there seems to be two mistakes. Maple disagrees with the equality that ends by "-8", and there's also something wrong with how you went from the previous line to that line.